# Realtime timer that counts down time for ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1, timer

Im in the need on some advise for a realtime serverside timer that would countdown from say 100 seconds. Reason for serverside timer is no tampering.

- currently use delayed job but problem its not realtime i could mimic a timer by creatind job every second, but dirty solution
- need to display time in view by getting timer value with ajax call to method that returns servertime on page. Know how to do this just to give idea. reload timer would still countdown correctly even on reload page.

Anyone could advise to get a realtime counter in rails app serverside? I would want to create one or more independant timers i can get a value from in railsapp.

Comment: Why does it matter?  Why wouldn't just having a time that you count down to work?

Comment: Yes could also but need it yo be servertimer running like deamon in background quering it for the time in my railsapp. I need this functionality for good reason to complex to drscribe

Comment: If the reason is that complex, it probably isn't as good a reason as you think it is.  Simplicity is almost always better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just create the record you need, but add a "don't open before" DateTime field you can check to see if it's okay to show it?

This sort of thing is trivial to do, and you can set a timer on the client to count-down in JavaScript, then reload the page with the final data at the appropriate time. If someone is impatient and reloads early, you can compute the number of seconds remaining before it can be shown using simple math:

```
time_left_in_seconds = record.show_at.to_i - Time.now.to_i
```

Then all you have to do is show a JavaScript timer for that number of seconds, then trigger a page refresh.

Comment: Great partly solution on the view side but could be tampered with by editing the JS? I need to serverside reload the page with some params from the app not sure thats possible with your solution but for solving the timer countdown could work great thx!

Comment: You can hack around with the client-side timer all you want and it won't change the fact that your server will refuse to cough up the goods until the `show_at` time has arrived. You can reload the page if you want, or use the useful jQuery `get` function to refresh part of it.